# Поиск фрагмента текста в файле от фрагмента до символа

Tags: java

```
public class ReplaceInFile {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String fileName = "file.txt";
        String search = "31415";
        String replace = "число ПИ";
        Charset charset = StandardCharsets.UTF_8;
        Path path = Paths.get(fileName);
        Files.write(path,
            new String(Files.readAllBytes(path), charset).replace(search, replace)
                .getBytes(charset));
    }
}
```

В этом классе я ищу фграгмент текста в файле по полному совпадению. Как сделать так что-бы после полного совпадения программа считывала строку до символа `;` ?

Пример поиска

Файл:

```
IP=123123; CONNECT=456456; DADADA dadada;
DATA=321321;
```

Если я ищу CONNECT= то его значение нужно считать до знака `;`.

Comment: Приведите пример файла, пример искомой строки и желаемый результат

Comment: @vp_arth Привёл

Comment: А если ищете `CONN`, результат должен быть `ECT=456456`?

Comment: @vp_arth Нет, я ищу только полностью. Нужно считать после = до ;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно сделать так:

```
String fileName = "file.txt";
String text = "CONNECT";
String delimiter = ";";
Optional<String> result =
               Files
                    .lines(Paths.get(fileName))
                    .filter(e -> e.contains(text))
                    .map(e -> {
                        int start = e.indexOf(text);
                        int end = e.indexOf(delimiter, start + text.length());

                        return e.substring(start, end);
                    })
                    .findFirst();

result.ifPresent(System.out::println);
```

Данное решение позволяет не считывать весь файл целиком.

Comment: Ответ не совсем правильный, так как он считывает результат вместе с искомой переменной `text`.

Answer (score 2):

Решение, используя регулярные выражения.
Ищет "значение" между "CONNECT=" и ";" в строке

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    String string = "IP=123123; CONNECT=456456; DADADA dadada;";

    String pattern1 = "CONNECT=";
    String pattern2 = ";";

    Pattern p = Pattern.compile(Pattern.quote(pattern1) + "(.*?)" + Pattern.quote(pattern2));
    Matcher m = p.matcher(string);
    while (m.find()) {
        System.out.println(m.group(1));
    }
}
```

Comment: Хорошо, что посмотрел перед тем, как отправить идентичное решение...

Comment: Matcher m = p.matcher(new String(Files.readAllBytes(path), charset)); - строка из примера